# Meteor TypeError: braintree.setup is not a function

Tags: javascript, meteor, braintree

I am trying to work on braintree for our app but it seems like I keep on getting same error. I installed braintree-web successfully (twice) and I am importing braintree. I am using the correct client token.

TypeError: braintree.setup is not a function

```
import braintree from 'braintree-web';

Template.braintree_payment.onRendered(function(){ 
    var clientToken = "abc....";

    console.log("logging");
    braintree.setup(clientToken, "dropin", {
      container: "payment-form"
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of braintree-web are you using? Version 2 should indeed have a `braintree.setup` function, but version 3 does not.

Version 3 should be initialised like so:

```
braintree.client.create({
  authorization: 'CLIENT_AUTHORIZATION'
}, function (err, clientInstance) {
  braintree.hostedFields.create(/* ... */);
});
```

Check out the docs for version 3 here: https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/client-sdk/setup/javascript/v3